# What is the meaning of "amplifies fluctuations into a circular flow"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, terminology

I could not solve the meaning of this phrase:

> amplifies fluctuations into a circular flow.

What does "amplify into" mean? Could you paraphrase the sentence for me?

The phrase context is below:

> When we explained convection by the causal mechanism outlined above — a temperature gradient that creates a density gradient that, in turn, *amplifies fluctuations into a circular flow* — we were giving only part of the explanation because the causal chain behind the emergence of a convection cell does not account for the fact that its properties are stable against perturbations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK:

> amplifies fluctuations into a circular flow.

Let's look at each part of the sentence separately:

- "Amplifies … into": Our context has to do with waves (fluctuations) in heat.  To amplify waves means to make them "louder" or more intense by increasing their magnitude.  Since the phrase is "amplify into" we are turning something into something else by making it more intense.
- "fluctuations": Fluctuations are like waves, but more general.  It means that something is oscillating, or going back and forth.  In this case, they are oscillations in temperature.
- "circular flow": This means that the heat is now continuously moving in a circle.

**To summarize:** The sentence means, in simpler terms, "Makes waves of heat stronger and causes them to move continuously in a circle."

Answer (score 0):

The term **fluctuations** is typically used to describe random motion of molecules.

In "steady state" of gas or liquid, all molecules fluctuate, but the average (or "net") movement is zero; think of it as people moving around in a ballroom but not getting in or out of it.

If there is a **temperature gradient** (simply put, hot and cold regions and a transition between them) then, when you look at a single molecule, it still flucuates; but the density gradient (caused by the temperature gradient) sort of **amplifies** the fluctuations with a preference to one direction. The result is that the fluctuations sum out to a nonzero net **flow**.

Therefore, we can say that the temperature gradient amplifies the fluctuations **into** a flow.

The reason for the flow being **circular** is probably beyond the scope of ELL (even more than my answer is already...); it is a scientific topic.